# C++ SFML sprite position not updating when in function

Tags: c++, sfml

So I have a sprite named player.

If I enter

```
player.move(3,4);
```

in my loop then the player moves that much each frame.

However if I make a function.

```
int updatePlayerPos(sf::Sprite player1)
{
player1.move(3, 4);
return 0;
}
```

and then call that in the main loop using

```
updatePlayerPos(player);
```

It does not do anything.

What mistake am I making?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the sprite is passed by value, meaning the function have a *copy* of the sprite. You can do anything with the copy, but the original will not change at all. You would want to pass it by reference instead:

```
int updatePlayerPos(sf::Sprite& player1)
//                            ^
//          Note the ampersand
```